# Usage of "is" and "does" 

Tags: grammatical-number, auxiliary-verbs

Which sentence is correct?

> The directory is not exist

OR

> The directory does not exist

This message informs a user about a folder he or she is trying to access.

Comment: I don't think this question is really op topic for this website. Questions about basic grammar can be looked up in pages such as this one: http://www.fortunecity.com/bally/durrus/153/gramch02.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct negation is:

> The directory *does* not exist.

Here, *do* functions as an auxiliary for emphasis/negation. Consider the positive form of the sentence where *do* is optional:

> The directory *does* exist / The directory exists

It should be clearer here that *is* is not appropriate:

> The directory *is* exist (?)

Also, note that whenever *be* is used as an auxiliary, it precedes participles and infinitives. Hence, the following examples are grammatical:

> - ... the directory *is* to exist
> - the directory *is* existing

Comment: "The directory exist" is incorrect.  I'd say "The directory exists" (s on the end of exist).  So I don't think your second quoted sentence works (either as "The directory [does] exist" or "The directory [does] exists".

Comment: @Peter K. Totally correct. I didn't notice that at all. Will edit right away.

Answer (score 3):

> The directory does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct.

> The directory does not exist.

Comment: Your overall answer is correct but you introduced more errors by capitalizing the word dictionary and using the wrong tense for the verb. It should be just "exist" without the 's'.

Comment: Aah. Apologies about that . Its now corrected

Comment: I removed my downvote, but other folks have long since beaten you to the punch with the right answer with good explanations. Also it's a little confusing that you switched the vocabulary of the example from "directory" to "dictionary". Just something to keep in mind as you answer questions :) Thanks for participating.

Answer (score 1):

Of your two examples, the correct sentence is

> The directory does not exist.

However, given your context, that is likely not very helpful to your user.

A more appropriate response would be to reference the folder directly:

> *This* directory does not exist.

or

> The directory you are trying to access does not exist.